# Pandas indexing by slicing and selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

Cannot imagine this has not been asked before, but cant find a similar post.
Q: Suppose you have a pandas dataframe with m columns (df.shape == (nxm)). I would like to extract a subset of columns by slicing and selecting columns, something that looks like:
`df1 = df.iloc[:,[a,b,c:d]]`. Is this possible? In this example the result should instantiate a dataframe in df1 with columns a,b and c till d of dataframe df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass either a list of integers or a slice to `iloc`, but not both at once. Numpy has the [`r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) function you can use to convert `[a,b,c:d]` to a list.

```
import numpy as np

df1 = df.iloc[:, np.r_[a,b,c:d]]
```

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I am looking for, thank you